# How to set up a proper select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I am trying to draw the end result being that `@gallery = whatever i choose in my select`

```
  - form_for :gallery do |f|
    .grid_6.hr_dots.clear

    .exist_gal
      .grid_5
        %label 
          2. Or add to an existing Gallery
      .clear
      .grid_4
        = select @gallery, :gallery, options_for_select(@galleries.collect { |g| g.name }), {}, :class => "gallery_title"
      .grid_2
        = link_to 'add photos', new_photos_organization_media_gallery_url(@organization.id, @gallery.id), :class => 'button add_photos_btn'
```

My controller :

```
def new
  @gallery = Gallery.new
  @galleries = @organization.galleries
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
    = f.select :gallery, options_for_select(@galleries.collect { |g| [g.name, g.id] }), {}, :class => "gallery_title"
```

**EDIT**: looking at your form again, you are doing `form_for :gallery`. Does `Gallery` have a field named `gallery` or is it `Organization` that has `gallery`?

Comment: Hmm the background to this is its a temporary var I need to just set what the the url is when I send them to add to their gallery. Maybe a good place for an attr_accessor (not sure what those are really). Yes Organization has many galleries. Gallery does not have a field named gallery.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Maybe I can't picture the flow of the application so I'm having a hard time understanding. Are you storing anything in the database? If not, then yes, an attr_accessor might be the way to go.